# How to insert post into a page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, css

i created a custom_post_type:

```
 add_action('init', 'event_register');

function event_register() {

$labels = array(
  'name' => _x('Pacotes', 'post type general name'),
  'singular_name' => _x('pacote', 'post type singular name'),
  'add_new' => _x('adicionar', 'pacote'),
  'add_new_item' => __('Adicionar novo Pacote'),
  'edit_item' => __('Editar Pacote'),
  'new_item' => __('Novo Pacote'),
  'view_item' => __('Ver Pacote'),
  'search_items' => __('Procurar Pacote'),
  'not_found' =>  __('Não encontrado'),
  'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nada encontrado no lixo'),
  'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
);

register_post_type( 'pacotes' , $args );
}
```

when i create post it does not appear in the page.
is there any code that calls for the posts?

thank you.

Comment: It doesn't appear on what page? The blog page?

Comment: Would be nice if you read my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue here is you need to refresh your permalinks for it to recognise the post type. Classic fix is to go to Settings > Permalinks and then click Save Changes without actually saving anything. Just loading the permalinks setting page usually fixes it, but saving makes sure.

I'd say that'll fix the issue.